# First digit is cut off in DateTimePicker with specific font

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2017

I'm using a `DateTimePicker` in my Windows Forms app with a custom format: `dd/MM/yyyy`.

The first digit is partially cut off when using the `Segoe UI Light` font as shown:

[image: First number cut off]

Adding spaces/symbols to the custom format (i.e. `"   dd/MM/yyyy"`) doesn't fix the problem. It only happens with `Segoe UI Light` (`Segoe UI Regular` is fine).

Apart from changing the font, how can I stop the first number from being cut off?

I'm using Visual Studio 2017, and the target .NET framework is 4.7.2.

Edit: Interestingly, if the custom format is set to `MM/dd/yyyy`, the first digit of the day is cut off: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2wry.jpg)

Comment: try to set Horizontal Alignment to center if it is set to left

Comment: I can't reproduce it with the font set to `Segoe UI Light, 10pt` or any other size. Perhaps there's another attribute somewhere? Looks like an oversight in the control, as it is immediately noticable if you change the font to italic. I can't think of a solution other than overwriting it or adding in a space

Comment: Actually, tried that and it's even weirder if you set it to dd2/MM/yyyy then the second digit is cut off (when italic). That is super weird. I'm gonna say it's a bug in the control and there's no workaround unless you want to override the paint method and draw it yourself.

Comment: @NibblyPig For me, italic is fine but light is broken; I might just have to switch fonts. apomene: I can't seem to find the horizontal alignment property or anything similar for the DateTimePicker anywhere.

Comment: There is no HorizontalAlignment on a Winforms DateTimePicker. However I am unable to reproduce the problem. Do you have some other configuration on the picker? Did you change the font at the Form level or just for that control?

Comment: If you set a font with specific weight, then reopen the font selection interface and you see that the selected Font is not selected anymore (you have to re-select it), then the Font is not exactly supported. Choose another weight. `SemiLight` should be fine.

Comment: @Steve I've played around with it a bit more. If the day contains a 1 then it won't get cut off (21 and 31 will work fine while 22, 23 etc. will not). I think I might just use another font.

Answer (score 0):

Increase or decrease date picker font size. Set integer value in font size.

Comment: Please elaborate, ideally demonstrate.